# Calling java server side method using jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I need to call java class method inside jquery , how do i do that ?

For more understanding Ex:

```
Class Foo{
      public static void letsCall(){
          // Do something here ...
      }
}
```

I want to call this `letsCall()` Method from jquery.

Comment: Expose the method using a servlet and call it. You should consider implementing a proper, simple RESTful web service just to keep it nice and clear.

Comment: try with jsp  like <%=function%>

Comment: I dont want to use JSP or servlets for this , only jquery call to Java Class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 approach:-

in jquery api, to call any backend system , in your case java, you need to do ajax call to invoke your java controller or service.

[jquery ajax post call (call your java controller here)](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

> 2nd approach:-

if you need java class to take part in your jsp formation , you can go for custom tags, in your case you can look for jsf framework which basically bind your user events to your controller.

other frameworks - springmvc bind your jsp attributes to its corresponding models, in this case no need to use jquery , you can achieve it through spring custom tags.

[spring mvc example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/)

spring custom tags example

[spring custom tag example](http://sloanseaman.com/wordpress/2012/03/26/spring-custom-tags-extensible-xml-part-1/)

Comment: Thanks, I liked first approach , but it tends to use url as shown below,$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
}); So , what do i pass in place of URL in my scenario .. As in i dont have a url to nevigate , just a java class with some methods...

Comment: @ashish yeah your java class will reside in server, so you should provide your server location and controller action to which your request will be directed. see this link http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-jquery-autocomplete-example/

Comment: if you want your jquery to call you java class, you need to host your java in a server and only through host url you can access your java class.. i dont know whether you can invoke plain pojo from jquery, it is not possible

Comment: I solved my Problem , i used Jetty handler to recieve requests , Process it & generate responses ..

Answer (score 0):

[Calling a backend Java method from JavaScript/jQuery in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273534/calling-a-backend-java-method-from-javascript-jquery-in-jsp)

[Calling Java inside JavaScript Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710382/calling-java-inside-javascript-function)

There are maybe a half dozen more similarly worded questions, please google first!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html). We use it a lot to do this kind of thing and it works well. It wraps all the ajax stuff so you don't have to worry about it.